# Caliburn Micro Viewmodel change variable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

I have this viewmodel http://pastebin.com/iVGYuPp1 in Caliburn micro and I need to detect when the View Actually activates because when I call the picker to pick a file on WP8.1 the app gets reactivated on Windows Phone 8.1 after choosing the file and therefore I have to change the value of the Tags property.

I am new to caliburn micro and I am not sure on how to achieve this. Picker is a Singleton class instantiated in App.xaml.cs.

Thank you everybody.

EDIT: on Windows Store side I have no problems since it has an awaitable method to get a file with a picker.

Answer (score 1):

If you derive your ViewModel (or in your case your ViewModelBase) from `Screen` your can override the `OnActivate` methods that gets called every time the ViewModel is activated (rough equivalent of OnNavigateTo in View).

Comment: I tried using that but it does not work in my case. Every time i get back to that view OnActivated does not fire. It activates only when the app is started.

Comment: This http://pastebin.com/x8BcFpKR is how I use OnActivated in the App.xaml.cs (could this pe my problem). IFilePickerService.ContinueAsync is the function that picks the file

Comment: Are you not using PhoneBootstrapperBase on your bootstrapper for your probject?  Application startup is slightly different and configured very differently between windows 8 and windows phone 8.  Win8 uses a modified App.xaml.cs and Windows Phone 8 uses a bootstrapper.